# Declaring protocol like @class

Tags: objective-c

I have two protocols communicating with each other. They are defined in the same file.

```
@protocol Protocol1 <NSObject>
-(void)setProtocolDelegate:(id<Protocol2>)delegate;
@end

@protocol Protocol2 <NSObject>
-(void)protocol:(UIViewController<Protocol1>*)anObject chosenElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)aIndex;
@end
```

How to declare an empty protocol `Protocol2` just to let know compiler that it is declared later?

If `Protocol2` was a class I'd write `@class Protocol2;` beforewards.

```
@class Protocol2;
@protocol Protocol1 <NSObject>
-(void)setProtocolDelegate:(Protocol2*)delegate;
@end

@interface Protocol2 <NSObject>
-(void)protocol:(UIViewController<Protocol1>*)anObject chosenElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)aIndex;
@end
```

What is the similar construction for protocols?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use @protocol for protocols forward declaration:

```
@protocol Protocol2;
@protocol Protocol1 <NSObject>
-(void)setProtocolDelegate:(id<Protocol2>)delegate;
@end

@protocol Protocol2 <NSObject>
-(void)protocol:(UIViewController<Protocol1>*)anObject chosenElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)aIndex;
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your is that you have forward declared protocol with @class keyword.
It should be @protocol.

Comment: I know that it shouldn't be `@class`. I used second snippet to show analogy with Classes, to make the question clearer. Anyway, thanks for help